# NumPy Array vs. a regular Python list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on a program that stores stock data in an array.  The program is still in progress.  The program pulls data from yahoo finance and the data is store in a numpy array.  If the stock reaches a new high, an alert will pop up.

Here are some questions:

1. Why do I have to use a numpy array to perform this function instead of a regular list? In another word, what are the advantages or features of a numpy array?
2. Can you show me how I can learn more about numpy.loadtxt?  I tried looking to http://www.numpy.org

Thank you very much and below is the program I have so far...

```
    import urllib2
    import time
    import datetime
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates


    def pullData(stock):                    

    try:
        print 'Pulling ' + stock 
        print str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time())).strftime('%Y-%m-%d    %H:%M:%S'))

    urltovisit = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/csv' 
    stockFile = []
    try:
        f = urllib2.urlopen(urltovisit)      
        sourceCode = f.read().decode('utf-8')         
        splitSource = sourceCode.split('\n')              

        for eachLine in splitSource:                
            splitLine = eachLine.split(',')         
            fixMe = splitLine[0]
            if len(splitLine) == 6:                 
                 if 'values' not in eachLine:       
                     fixed =  eachLine.replace(fixMe,str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(fixMe)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
                     stockFile.append(fixed)
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e), 'failed to organize pulled data'

    date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(stockFile,delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters={ 0: mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')})

    if highp[-1] == max(highp):
        print stock + ' New high ' + str(max(highp)) 
    else:
        print ' no new high '
except Exception, e:
    print str(e), 'failed to pull pricing data'


  stockName = raw_input('Enter a stock: ')   
  pullData(stockName)
```

Comment: 1. Read the [FAQ](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#id6). 2. Read the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Comment: Python lists are bizarrely implemented as arrays instead of linked lists, so I believe the performance difference between the two should not make a huge difference. If it was a true linked list than I would vote list because inserts to the end are O(1) and you are doing lots of inserts, but because it is not I think arrays and lists will have comparable performance.

Comment: @Tommy, a more formal name for "bizarrely implemented as arrays" is `dynamic arrays`, and I am not sure what is "bizarre" about it.

Comment: Thanks MattDMo for the link to the docs. Is there something special that the numpy array can do and the python list cannot do?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I guess I'm old school; list to me screams "linked list", so I find the naming deceiving/bizarre. For inserts, linked lists are faster than even these dynamic arrays. I am not a fan of not having these two datatypes merged because their operation efficiencies are different for different operations. Having said that I'm sure you can get a linked list in Python.

Comment: I am willing to bet people that have not look in depth into the Python language assume lists are linked lists. I did for years until I actually read the details of how they are implemented.

Comment: @Tommy, I thought lists were linked lists for a while too; I guess it is a common misconception.

Comment: I think partly the reason for using dynamic arrays to implement list is that you then get O(1) random access, so in a sense that is not that bizarre to implement it that way.

Comment: My point which was missed is that it is named poorly because most people would assume linked list when it is called "list". THAT is why the misconception exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some useful information can be found [here](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#what-advantages-do-numpy-arrays-offer-over-nested-python-lists) and [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/whatisnumpy.html).

The main advantage of numpy arrays is that they are much, much faster than Python lists when performing most numerical operations.  For instance, multiplying every element in a sequence by a single other constant, or multiplying every element in one sequence by the corresponding element in another sequence, is much faster in numpy.  In addition, for multidimensional structures, numpy arrays support more powerful indexing, for instance allowing you to slice by both rows and columns.

Because of this fundamental advantage, numpy arrays have become the de facto standard for basically every Python project that does heavy number crunching.  This means that many other tools are built on numpy arrays (for instance, graphing with matplotlib, machine learning with scikit-learn, etc.).